# What is netshell equivalent command in Powershell for Reserving Url?

Tags: powershell, netsh

In *netshell* we use something like this:

```
http add urlacl url=https://+:{0}/ user={1}
```

I need equivalent functionality to be achieved in *Powershell* or any tool other than *netsh*.

Can you give me direction?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply tell Powershell to execute the command directly from PS by running the command as follows:

```
$port=9080
$domainUser="Everyone"
& netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:$port/ user=$domainUser
```

The `&` (ampersand) is a call operator that will tell Powershell to execute the netsh command

Otherwise if for whatever reason netshell is not available on the target machine, you can use

> Httpcfg.exe tool

to configure http and https: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx